# How to analyze/view *.run and *.out files?

Tags: c#, logging, outlook, add-in, trace

I used tttracer_Win7 tool to trace an exception of my addin when it was integrated to Outlook 2013. And the output file of the tool had 2 files: *.out and *.run, but I dont know how to view the files. Tried Google Search, and did not help me. The tool also could not read that files.

Could you give me some comment, or suggest about some tool that can do that?

Here is the UI of the tool, I hope you guys used to use it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a log file instead. Thus, you will be able to find the cause of the issue easily. For example, you can use [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) library.